# Retorno de número não numérico NaN no PHP

Tags: javascript, number-format

Estou tendo problemas na exibição dos dados de uma Orçamento já imputado no banco de dados. Ao acessar o detalhamento está exibindo o `R$ NaN` nos campos de moeda.

Código de algumas funções:

**orcamento.js**

```
function sumTotal() {
    var novo_total = 0;
    $('#bodyOrcamento tr').each(function(index, element) {
        if (!$(element).hasClass('etapa')) {
            novo_total += Number($(element).children("td:nth-child(7)").html());
        }
    });
    var custo_total = $('#custoTotal_orc');
    custo_total.html(novo_total.toFixed(2));
}

function salvarOrcamento() {

    var id = $("#codigo").val();
    var descricao = $("#descricao_orc").html();
    var empreendimento = $("#empreendimento_orc").data('id');
    var custo = Number($("#custoTotal_orc").html());
}
```

O HTML

```
             <table class="table hide table-bordered grid" id="tabelaOrcamento">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="">
                        <th scope="col" title="Item">Item</th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Código">Código</th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Descrição">Descrição</th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Unidade">Unidade</th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Custo Unitário">Custo Unitário</th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Quantidade">Quantidade</th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Custo Total">Custo Total</th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Ações">Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="bodyOrcamento"></tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span style="font-size:15px;">Valor Total:</span><br>
                <span style="font-size:30px;"><b>R$ <span id="custoTotal_orc">0.00</span></b></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: O que tem dentro da `td` de onde vc quer pegar o número? Apenas o número ou possui tags ou outra coisa que não seja o número?

Comment: dê um `console.log($(element).children("td:nth-child(7)").html())` e veja se o retorno é um número `int` ou `float`

Comment: @sam, atualizado com o HTML.

Comment: Tem que mostrar o conteúdo da `td` de onde vem o valor.